# How to get default language in an add-on?

Tags: multi-language, language

Is there a way to get the default language set in *Admin -> General Configuration* in an add-on(module, extension, plugin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a config item, so you can get it using the Config object, thus:

```
ee()->config->item('deft_lang');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I originally though it was `ee()->config->item('language')` but I was wrong.